# Call recording SID from twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

I could make a call and record call conversation.
string callerId =string.Empty;//Twillio Account SID
 var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId, record: record_from_answer
How to retrieve  Recording Sid of the current call, once the call recording is complete from Twilio using c#

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is C# code, I have used Dial method to call to the specific user and record their conversation.I am able to call and record both the side conversation using the above-mentioned code.But now I want to get the Recording SID of that call once the recording is complete.Please help

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio will make a request to your server with the recording information via the `RecordingStatusCallback` attribute. You can read more about it [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#attributes-recording-status-callback)

So all you need is create an endpoint that accepts a `POST` request from Twilio and change your code to something like:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
            response.Dial("to-phone-number",
            callerId: "your-twilio-number",
            record: "record-from-answer",
            recordingStatusCallback: new Uri("url_in_your_application_that_processes_recordings")
            );
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you  for your quick response.Could  you please  send me  a sample  url  for  this -recordingStatusCallback: new Uri("url_in_your_application_that_processes_recordings").......
 Isit  an  api?